# Add comments around selected text

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

Does anyone know how to get the selected content in comments by pressing `Cmd + /` (or `Ctrl + /` on Windows) in Visual Studio Code?

What I want:

```
.content/*,
.site-header .widget-area*/ {
    width: 800px;
}
```

What happens currently:

```
/* .content,
.site-header .widget-area { */
    width: 800px;
}
```

Comment: Yeah it'll comment out the selected lines and not the selected content.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> will toggle **Line Comment**, and what you want is to toggle **Block Comment** instead.

The default shortcut for  that is <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> for the `editor.action.blockComment` command.

See the [Key Bindings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings) page for more shortcuts.